# Twitter: Smooth scrolling with TabLayout pin at top

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How does Twitter app implement their smooth scrolling with `TabLayout` that pins at the top?

[Twitter app gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLFBt.gif)

I have tried the various combination of `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout`, `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, and `TabLayout`/`ViewPager`. The closest I have is the following hierarchy.

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppbarLayout>
        <CollapsingToolbarLayout layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <ImageView />
            <LinearLayout />
            <Toolbar layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </CollapsingToolbarLayout >
    </AppbarLayout>
<LinearLayout layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <TabLayout />
    <ViewPager />
</LinearLayout>
```

There are 2 problems I am trying to solve.

1 - Sometimes fling gesture gets bounced and applied to the opposite direction. 
2 - I want one fling to scroll smoothly to the top and bottom. Currently, one fling to the top will once pause at `TabLayout`. Then I need to pull/fling up to reach the very top of the screen.

I am aware of this known bug with fling gesture in support library, but Twitter doesn't seem to have this bug. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176589

[Edit]
I have looked at these questions.

[Android: pin TabLayout to top of Scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110756/android-pin-tablayout-to-top-of-scrollview)

[Android Toolbar and User Image Animation Like Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37037621/android-toolbar-and-user-image-animation-like-twitter)

Comment: @Saeid Did you mean to post your comment on this question asked right after mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406551/getuidtxbytesint-uid-always-return-0-in-android-6-0

Comment: @Saeid Your link is about `getUidRxBytes() and getUidTxBytes() always return 0 in Android 4.3`. I don't think it's related to my question.

Comment: ohhhh sorry i mistake - i delete last comments - i'm so sorry

Comment: Hey did you figure it out???

Comment: Hey did you figure it out???